# Custom Object -- duplicate record

Tags: list, duplicate-management

I have a custom object and we have a lot of records of same name under it, how do i make a list with no duplicate values in list

Comment: You wish to store only those records in the list which have unique name(eliminating all records with same name) right?

Comment: @Pankaj Can u please elaborate with some example so that it will easy to understand your query. Lot of records with same name under it means --> Are you referring to a particular Field with column as "Name", also the List u referring is to a List view? Can u confirm?

Comment: @Abhijeet yes -- it's a proper record and that's a list not that list view

Answer (score 0):

Using the following SOQL:

```
Select Name, count(Id) From Your_Obj__c group by Name Having count(Id) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list of records(which contains duplicates) and then use a map to store records with key value pair as

> (name,record)

Then use the values() method on the map to get records in a list which are all unique.Below is the approach that you can use:

```
    for(Custom_Object__c objCustom:lstDuplicateItems){

    mapNameRecords.put(objCustom.name,objcustom);//if duplicate record comes from the list, the previous duplicate record stored in the map will be overridden.

    }

List<Custom_Object__c> lstUniqueRecords = mapNameRecords.values();

// lstUniqueRecords now contains unique records
```

This should work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you execute below code in developer console, you can remove duplicare records, assuming you have less than 50000 records.
If you have more records then, you need to write a batch class.

```
List<CustomObject__c> duplicateRecordList = new List<CustomObject__c>();
Set<String> stNames = new Set<String>();

for(CustomObject__c objRecord : [Select Id, Name From CustomObject__c limit 50000])
{
    if(stNames.contains(objRecord.Name))
    {
        duplicateRecordList.add(objRecord);
    }
    else
    {
        stNames.add(objRecord.Name);
    }
}

delete duplicateRecordList;
```

Once you remove all duplicates, you can think of setting a [Duplicate Management Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_prevention_map_of_tasks.htm&language=en_US) for that Custom Object to avoid duplicates in future.

You can also think of creating a Trigger to avoid duplicate records in future.